# Javamail sustain gmail's "sign out all other sessions"

Tags: java, oauth, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

**Background:**

I'm trying to monitor my gmail inbox for certain kinds of emails and take action. I've successfully setup my account to monitor my inbox using javamail's [addMessageCountListener.messagesAdded()](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Folder.html#addMessageCountListener%28javax.mail.event.MessageCountListener%29) to listen to new mails and I'm idling the thread until a new message arrives.

**Problem:**

I want my javamail to stay logged in, even after I accidentally clicked on "*Sign out all other sessions*" button.

[image: Sign out all other sessions]

I know this is possible because my mobile phone's gmail session (using the gmail's native app) is resilient to this.

Comment: Wouldn't you simply need to have your program log back in??

Comment: Good idea. But, I want it to work autonomous (without my interactions) 
On the same note: If there is any way to detect if it's been logged out, then I can take required actions to log back in!

Comment: Been a very long time since I've used `JavaMail` but I'd imagine it would be throwing an error some where when you try and download the  mail.  Either that, or you could log yourself out after each cycle and just simple log back in when you need to...

Comment: Most people just save the username and password from the first time connect is called and call connect again if the Store is closed unexpectedly.  I believe JavaMail will also save the username and password from a successful connect allowing you to call connect() with no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the comments/hints. Here is a quick write-up in java. In case others might need it.

**Of course, Any comments/feedback/reviews/potential problems on this below code are most welcome :)**

```
package com.anand.test;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.FolderClosedException;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.event.ConnectionEvent;
import javax.mail.event.ConnectionListener;
import javax.mail.event.MessageCountEvent;
import javax.mail.event.MessageCountListener;

import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder;
import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore;

class GMailStayConnect {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        MailConnector m = new MailConnector("uname", "pwd");
        Thread newThrd = new Thread(m);
        newThrd.start();
    }
}

class StoreGetter {
    public static IMAPSSLStore getGStore(String uname, String passw){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(true);

        IMAPSSLStore store = new IMAPSSLStore(session, null);
        try {
            store.connect(uname, passw);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return store;
    }
}

class MailConnector implements Runnable {
    private String uname = "";
    private String passw = "";

    public MailConnector(String uname, String passw) {
        this.uname = uname;
        this.passw = passw;
    }

    public void run() {
        IMAPSSLStore store = StoreGetter.getGStore(uname, passw);
        try {
            IMAPFolder inbox = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener() {
                public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent e) {
                    // My custom action goes here on e.getMessages()
                }

                public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent e) {
                    // My custom action goes here on e.getMessages()
                }
            });
            inbox.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {
                public void opened(ConnectionEvent e) {
                    // System.out.println("Opened !!");
                }

                public void disconnected(ConnectionEvent e) {
                    // System.out.println("Disconnected !!");
                }

                public void closed(ConnectionEvent e) {
                    // System.out.println("Closed !!");
                    // Another place to handle reconnecting
                }
            });
            while (true) {
                inbox.idle();
            }
        } catch (FolderClosedException e1) {
            // Place to handle reconnecting
            GMailStayConnect.main(null);
        } catch (MessagingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```